# mifare 4k classic write does not work as expected

Tags: nfc, apdu, mifare

I want to write to a mifare classic 4k, using the following APDU command (UPDATE BINARY):

```
APDU = {FF D6 00 20 10 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0Fh}
```

It seems fine as a get a `90 00` result...
but when i read the card back I always got the following (even with different data...):

```
sector: 8 (block 32), auth OK
032: D5 41 00 EA 00 FF 13 3E 86 6A 00 00 00 00 69 FF
033: D5 41 00 EA 00 FF 13 3E 86 6A 00 00 00 00 69 FF
034: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
035: 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 07 80 69 FF FF FF FF FF FF
```

where does this string `D5 41 00 EA 00 FF 13 3E 86 6A 00 00 00 00 69 FF` come from?

Note that i didn't change any setting on the card and was properly authenticated. It was a blank card and i didn't touch the trailer.

I m using a ACR122 reader (this command comes direct from the documentation of the reader...)

Comment: I guess you are using some USB reader? As Mifare Classic's don't respond directly to ADPU's and any APDU beginning with FF is a pseudo wrapper ADPU. So it would be helpful to know the make and model of the reader as some can wrap ADPU's differently.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, i updated the question, im using a ACR122

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found my problem, i was setting the wrong size for the `cbSendLength` parameter in `SCardTransmit`.

Now i set the correct one (the whole size of the APDU command: 21) and it works fine.

Sorry.

Comment: My next comment on your question was going to be show your actual code as you had just given that data you were sending and not how you were sending it and thus people would never have got this answer for you.